# How do you find the Ubuntu version (release number / name) from the command line?

Tags: ubuntu, debian

How do you find the Ubuntu version (release number / name) from the command line?

Comment: Related (cross site): *[How can I find the version of Ubuntu that is installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12493)*

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Run `lsb_release` with the `-a` switch.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 9.04
Release:    9.04
Codename:   jaunty
```

Comment: That works on any LSB compliant distribution, right? I tried it on my debian 6 (squeeze) install, and it worked too.

Comment: Yes. The command 'lsb_release' is from the Linux Standards Base. From the man page; "The lsb_release command provides certain LSB (Linux Standard Base) and distribution-specific information."

Comment: `lsb_release -rs` will provide the version # alone too

Answer (score 11):

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 8.10 \n \l
```

Comment: It's worth remembering that /etc/issue may be edited by admins to give a different welcome message..

Comment: This is a useful fallback on non-LSB compliant systems.  So is /etc/debian_version (if present), it's a debian based distro.  I don't know if Ubuntu leaves the debian_version file there or makes an /etc/Ubuntu_version file though.

Comment: I have a Docker image where I'm not `root` and don't have `lsb_release` (and the Ubuntu image it's built on is apparently far up the docker dependency chain), this worked well to suss out which Ubuntu it's running absent `lsb_release`. Also, FWIW @WarrenP I'm seeing `/etc/debian_version` on this (virtual) machine

Answer (score 2):

`source` from `/etc/lsb-release` to export version information variables into your shell:

```
$ . /etc/lsb-release
```

Contains the following variables

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `/etc/lsb-release` directly. The spec requires you to query using the `lsb_release` command which can query other sources of information.

Comment: I consider this an appropriate answer until someone bothers to write a command that goes through the `lsb_release` command and extracts these.

Comment: I have no lsb_release package installed and I am not sudo. It was useful for me!

Answer (score -3):

$ uname -a

Linux debian 2.7.30-1-686 #1 SMP Thu May 8 02:16:39 UTC 2008 i686 GNU/Linux

---

uname -a anaylsis:

Linux: is the kernel name.

debian: is the machine's hostname.

2.7.30-1-686: is the kernel version

1 SMP Thu May 8 02:16:39 UTC 2008: SMP stands for symmetric multiprocessing, denoting that the CPU (central processing unit) is using two or more CPUs and the current system date

i686: is the CPU architecture

GNU/Linux: is OS

Comment: -1, uname doesn't tell you the ubuntu version. lsb_release is the way to go.