# How to show version of currently installed Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you find the Ubuntu version (release number / name) from the command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/21634/how-do-you-find-the-ubuntu-version-release-number-name-from-the-command-line)

I have Ubuntu Linux installed on a computer. How can I check in the command line (no GUI desktop available) which version of the distribution it is running?

Answer (score 17):

Try this command:

`lsb_release -a`

It should give you a hint of the version.

Answer (score 4):

The command is:

$ cat /etc/lsb-release

Which will return Ubuntu specific version information

Or,

$ uname -a

which will give you information about the kernel and hardware